# Prevent accidental select/drag highlight

Tags: html, canvas, drawing, highlight

I have a drawing application using html5 canvas. When the user is drawing and pen slips out of the canvas area, chrome highlights html elements on the page in light blue or yellow.

[image: screen shot]

This is disruptive to the drawing experience.  Is there a way to prevent such highlight from happening?

The event handling and drawing code is based off of this post: http://jsfiddle.net/rnNFB/1/

```
var x ;
var y ;

var lower = $('#lower').get(0).getContext('2d') ;
var upper = $('#upper').get(0).getContext('2d') ;

var dragging = false ;

function drawStroke(ctx){
    var i ;
    ctx.strokeStyle='rgba(0,0,0,0.5)' ;
    ctx.lineWidth=10 ;
    ctx.beginPath() ;
    ctx.moveTo(x[0],y[0]) ;
    for (i=1; i < x.length; i++){
        ctx.lineTo(x[i],y[i]) ;
    }
    ctx.stroke() ;
}

$('#upper').mousedown(function(e){
    x=[e.layerX];
    y=[e.layerY];
    dragging=true}) ;

$('#upper').mousemove(function(e){
    if (dragging){
        x.push(e.layerX);
        y.push(e.layerY);
        upper.clearRect(0,0,upper.canvas.width,upper.canvas.height) ;
        drawStroke(upper) ;
    }}) ;

$('#upper').mouseup(function(e){
    dragging = false ;
    upper.clearRect(0,0,upper.canvas.width,upper.canvas.height) ;
    drawStroke(lower) ;
}) ;
```

If you add some h1 tags above the canvas tags then draw on the canvas, dragging outside the bounding box, you will see a blue highlight.  Is there a way to prevent this behavior?

Comment: This problem is not only limited to canvas.

Comment: Yes, it's applicable to any drag-and-drop, row selecting, etc, pretty much anything that's not simply text content related... I've found the answer below to be helpful in many contexts.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Apply the following CSS class to the elements that should be unselectable. It can also just be applied to body (though, best practise might be to only disable user selection on elements that really need it).

```
.unselectable {
  user-select: none;
}
```

**off-topic** but it might also be interesing for the app: If you select a big lineWidth in the jsFiddle and move the mouse very slowly, you can see some ugly effects (blocks) in the sketches. Always check that the distance from the onmousemove (while dragging) coordinate to the last coordinate is not too small. For example, only add the coordinates to the sketch if the distance is more than about 1/6 of the linewith.

Comment: this works thanks!  I will probably just have the entire page "unselectable" applied everywhere all the time because sometimes the mouseDown event accidentally occurs just outside the canvas as well.  Also, extra thanks for the tip about blocky lines!  I was wondering why that was occurring.  Thanks!

Comment: `user-select` is now supported by all major browsers (see http://caniuse.com/user-select-none). This simplifies the implementation. Just use `.css('user-select', 'none')`. If you need to support pre IE 10, you're out of luck and need to apply hacks.

Answer (score 5):

Try this script, it would disable selection if dragging is set to true.  This way you can still select text when you are not drawing.

```
document.onselectstart = function( e ) { 
  if (dragging) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't use *document*.onselectstart. All you have to do is put this on the canvas in question instead:

`canvas.onselectstart = function() { return false; };`

Additionally you could capture the mouse down/move/up events that are occuring on your canvas by setting the last argument of `addEventListener` to `true`. this will let your drawing continue perfectly even if the mouse leaves the canvas.

Comment: hmm, tried using canvas.onselectstart in my similar paint app, but it only disables selection when the mouse cursor is hovering the canvas.